# Refresh DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

using WPF/C#/Entity Framework. I have a `DataGrid.ItemsSource` bound to some `ObservableCollection`. Now, I add a new item to the collection but DataGrid doesn't refresh. I call `PropertyChanged` as well as `view.Refresh()` but nothing works. Please help me.

Comment: It sounds like your collection isn't bound correctly. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is `Datagrid.Items.Refresh()`

Comment: If you are able to post your code then it will be easier to work out what is going wrong. Is [this article](http://programmer.wrighton.org/2009/07/wpf-datagrid-items-refresh-part-ii.html) of any help?

Answer (score 0):

A [common practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/04/forcing-a-wpf-binding-to-refresh.aspx) to refresh controls that are bound to data is using UpdateTarget() of the binding expression:

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(myTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Did you try that?

Comment: I guess, it should be only possible by 1. collection change, 2. PropertyChanged("collection") call... but it's not.